# Right upper constraint format

Tags: swift, swift3, constraints

I am struggling with adding one button from code to the right corner of the `view`.
Could someone explain me how can i do this without setting the left constraint ? This would be the left upper  `V:|-10-[v0]`, `H:|-10-[v0]` what would be inversion of it ? I was trying with this : `V:[v0]-10-|`, `H:[v0]-0-|` but it does not work like i thought

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't use VFL (sic?) anymore, working with anchors instead. But looking at your "upper left" constraints, are you sure those work? Assuming *v0* is your button, you are stating that your button has 10 point margins on both the left and right and no margin vertically.

Comment: @dfd thx for point on misstyped, but still with this set up it was working.

Comment: Ok. I see the correction and know I still remember how to read VFL. :-) I read your "right " pin to be the *bottom* right, not *top*. Also, you either have a type on the horizontal or you want it on the right edge with no margin. What exactly are you seeing?

Comment: @dfd I would like to place botton on the right top.

Comment: @dfd btw. how would u put button using anchors to the right corner ? Would u use only top anchor fo superview and traling of the super view ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, I'd like to provide two answers on how to place a UIButton on the top right.

**VFL:**

Your vertical pin is for the bottom right, not the top. Instead of `V:[v0]-10-|`, where the "pipe" character (that designates the bounds of the screen) is at the end, place it at the beginning - `|-10-[v0]`.

Provided you've given the button some sort of height/width - which I think you have as the code for "top left" works - this should fix things.

**Anchors**

Introduced in iOS9, layout anchors (along with layout guides) are a third way to code auto layout. Like `NSLayoutConstraints`, this is less "visual" than VFL. But unlike `NSLayoutConstraints` it's less verbose - thus more "Swiftier" IMHO.

To pin a UIButton to the top left, you still need to give auto layout four things - height, width, and X/Y positions. In the following I'm assuming the superview of v0 is called `view`, like the root view of a `UIViewController`.

```
// declare your button
let v0 = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // remember, you ALWAYS need to turn of the auto resize mask!
    v0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(v0)

    // create a square button
    v0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true        
    v0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true

    // pin the button 10 points from the left side of the view
    v0.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true        

    // here's how you would pin the button 10 points from the right side of the view
    // note the use of a negative here!
    // v0.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true        

    // pin the button 10 points from the top of the view
    v0.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

}
```

Like `NSLayoutConstraints`, layout anchors have constants and multipliers, which you may change if you declare a name for the constraint.

You may combine `NSLayoutConstraints` with `NSLayoutGuides` for some nice "adaptive layouts". These guides act like "spacer/invisible" UIViews except for the overhead - they aren't views. You can get a set of Apple "standard" margins (UIView.layoutMarginsGuide), or you can create a set of equally size dynamic guides to space things out equally.

Here's two blogs about [layout anchors](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/pain-free-constraints-with-layout-anchors/) and [layout guides](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/goodbye-spacer-views-hello-layout-guides/). The examples are written in Swift 2 but there's no syntax changes for Swift 3.

Comment: works, but your inner view should be `view` not `v0`. Also add `.isActive = true`. Example: `v0.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true`